# Selecting nodes from XML returns 0 items

Tags: xml, vb.net

I am working with our Solarwinds API and my code is selecting nodes, but returning zero count. If I pull from another source, the code pulls in nodes correctly. Is there something about the feed that I need to account for? The only difference I see is encoding.

Here's a snippet of the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<result created="2020-04-18T15:06:26-05:00" host="www.systemmonitor.us" status="OK">
    <items>
        <client>
            <name>
                <![CDATA[Best Client]]>
            </name>
            <clientid>111111</clientid>
            <view_dashboard>0</view_dashboard>
            <view_wkstsn_assets>0</view_wkstsn_assets>
            <dashboard_username>
                <![CDATA[none]]>
            </dashboard_username>
            <timezone></timezone>
            <creation_date>2019-07-02</creation_date>
            <server_count>0</server_count>
            <workstation_count>2</workstation_count>
            <mobile_device_count>0</mobile_device_count>
            <device_count>2</device_count>
        </client>
</items>
</result>
```

And here is the VB.net code snippet:

```vb
        Dim myFeed As XmlDocument = AppShared.LoadXMLDocument(feedURL)
        Dim myXMLNodeList As XmlNodeList
        Dim xmlNode as XmlNode

        Console.WriteLine("Connected")

        '---select all of the clients in the feed
        If Not IsNothing(myFeed.SelectNodes("//client")) Then

            dim rmmClientID as Integer = 0
            dim clientName as string = 0
            dim serverCount as Integer = 0
            Dim workstationCount as Integer = 0
            dim mobileDeviceCount as Integer = 0
            dim deviceCount as Integer = 0

            myXMLNodeList = myFeed.SelectNodes("//client")
            Console.WriteLine("Has " & myXMLNodeList.Count & " items")
            For Each currentXMLNode As XmlNode In myXMLNodeList

                Console.WriteLine("Processing row...")
                rmmClientID = currentXMLNode.SelectSingleNode("//client").SelectSingleNode("//clientID").Value
                Console.WriteLine("ClientID: " & rmmClientID)


            Next


        Else
            Console.WriteLine("No Client Nodes.")
        End If
```

It's not saying "No client nodes", it's saying "has 0 items". I have tried selecting //items as well as //items/client. Same result.

Comment: It is better to use **LINQ to XML** API while dealing with XML in the .Net Framework.

Comment: 1) Perhaps `AppShared.LoadXMLDocument` is not doing what you intend. 2) It would be more efficient to use `Dim myXMLNodeList = myFeed.SelectNodes("//client")`, then `If myXMLNodeList.Count > 0 Then` otherwise it has to do that twice in the event that there are `<client>` nodes.

Comment: I saved your sample XML to a file. I then did `Dim myFeed As New XmlDocument()`    `myFeed.Load("C:\temp\SO61306500.xml")` `Dim myXMLNodeList = myFeed.SelectNodes("//client")`. `myXMLNodeList.Count` was 1, so I cannot reproduce the problem.

Comment: `rmmClientID = myFeed.SelectSingleNode("//client").SelectSingleNode("//clientid").FirstChild().Value`. Set `Option Strict On`. it'll make it easier.

Answer (score 0):

myFeed.SelectNodes("//client") won't be Nothing (or null), but an empty XmlNodeList

check the output of

Console.Writeline(myFeed.OuterXml)

whether the data actually contains a  node

Comment: Thank you so much! The outerxml lead me to determine that my initial call was missing an & sign, and so not authenticating correctly! Duh!

Answer (score 0):

Use xml linq :

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Module Module1
    Const FILENAME As String = "c:\temp\test.xml"
    Sub Main()
        Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(FILENAME)

        Dim clients As List(Of Client) = doc.Descendants("client").Select(Function(x) New Client() With { _
            .name = CType(x.Element("name"), String),
            .id = CType(x.Element("clientid"), Integer),
            .dashboard = CType(x.Element("view_dashboard"), Integer),
            .asset = CType(x.Element("view_wkstsn_assets"), Integer),
            .username = CType(x.Element("dashboard_username"), String),
            .timezone = CType(x.Element("timezone"), String),
            .creationDate = CType(x.Element("creation_date"), DateTime),
            .serverCount = CType(x.Element("server_count"), Integer),
            .workstationCount = CType(x.Element("workstation_count"), Integer),
            .mobileDeviceCount = CType(x.Element("mobile_device_count"), Integer),
            .deviceCount = CType(x.Element("device_count"), Integer)
        }).ToList()
    End Sub

End Module
Public Class Client
    Public Property name As String
    Public id As Integer
    Public dashboard As Integer
    Public asset As Integer
    Public username As String
    Public timezone As String
    Public creationDate As DateTime
    Public serverCount As Integer
    Public workstationCount As Integer
    Public mobileDeviceCount As Integer
    Public deviceCount As Integer
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

You were very close.  A couple changes.

First, SelectNodes returns a node collection object with count=0 if nothing is found (not null)

Second, don't re-query //client again and again.  Get the list one time, and use it as needed.

Finally, in your foreach loop, your currentXMLNode variable points to the client already, so the selectSingleNode xpaths are relative to the client, no need to crawl the document again.

Here's a working example.

```
Dim myXMLNodeList As XmlNodeList
                Dim xmlNode As XmlNode

                Console.WriteLine("Connected")

                ' Keep the node list around
                myXMLNodeList = myFeed.SelectNodes("//client")

                If myXMLNodeList.Count > 0 Then
                        Dim rmmClientID As Integer = 0
                        Dim clientName As String = 0
                        Dim serverCount As Integer = 0
                        Dim workstationCount As Integer = 0
                        Dim mobileDeviceCount As Integer = 0
                        Dim deviceCount As Integer = 0

                        Console.WriteLine("Has " & myXMLNodeList.Count & " items")
                        For Each currentXMLNode As XmlNode In myXMLNodeList
                                Console.WriteLine("Processing row...")

                                ' Fixed element name clientID
                                rmmClientID = currentXMLNode("clientid").Value
                                Console.WriteLine("ClientID: " & rmmClientID)
                        Next
                Else
                        Console.WriteLine("No Client Nodes.")
                End If
```

Comment: This returns "No client nodes" for me.

Comment: Well, this is super embarrassing. The outerxml showed me the real problem. I was missing a & in my call, thus causing an authentication issue. :|

Comment: Pretty normal stuff.  Please accept as the answer if it helped you out. Good luck.